# how to raise event if method was not called in last 5 seconds?

Tags: c#

Sorry about that probably too simple question but I do not know how to implement this. If certain method was not called for certain ammount of time I need to raise an event (when I receive this event I will try troubleshoot problem. This is kind of connetion problem and I need to be notified about it to try to solve it - i will change connection method.)

```
public void MethodThatShouldBeCalledFrequently // acutally datagram from UDP received
{
    // if not called for 5 seconds than raise event 
}
public event EventHandler</*no parameters*/> MethodNotCalledForFiveSeconds; // connection problem, switch from UDP to TCP
```

Comment: Can't you set new timer inside this method?

Comment: @anuragsn7 I can do anything inside this method

Comment: @anuragsn7 I need something like stopwatch but "vice versa" it should count down, starting from 5 seconds, and when 0 seconds it should raise an event. On each method call I should reset stopwatch to "5 seconds"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
public class Program
{
    private Timer timer;

    public Program()
    {
       InitializeTimer();
       StartTimerFromBeginning();
    }

    public void MethodThatShouldBeCalledFrequently()
    {
       StartTimerFromBeginning();
    }

    public event EventHandler MethodNotCalledForFiveSeconds;

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
       timer = new Timer(5000);
       timer.Elapsed += HandleTimerElapsed;
    }

    private void StartTimerFromBeginning()
    {
       timer.Stop();
       timer.Start();
    }

    private void HandleTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       MethodNotCalledForFiveSeconds(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: am I obligated to create `new` timer each time? can I reuse Timer? because method is called several thousands times per second...

Comment: @javapowered You are not - I've edited my answer so that the `Timer` is only created once and then restarted. At first I've thought that the `Timer` cannot be restarted, but a quick sample proved otherwise :)

Comment: thanks! marking answer as correct unless someone will be able to suggest something more beatiful :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a flag and set it to true when MethodThatShouldBeCalledFrequently is called.

```
     bool wasCalled = false;
    public void MethodThatShouldBeCalledFrequently // acutally datagram from UDP received
     {
        wasCalled = true;
      }
```

Use another method to check at each 5 secs if the flag is true or false, and if it's false then raise the event.